# Searching for array element with given string parameter

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods, collections

I am trying to write a findBook method for my BookCollection class.  It finds a book with a specified ISBN. I am having trouble finding a way to compare the different types of elements. We were given this method:

```
public void changePrice(String isbn, double price){
    int index = findBook(isbn);                                                //CREATE FINDBOOK METHOD TO HELP THIS METHOD
    if( index == -1){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("BookNotFound");
    }
    collection[index].setPrice(price); 
}
```

But I am confused on why the comparison of integer index is made to a findbook method with a string parameter. Basically, we have a collection of type Book[], and with the given parameter isbn, have to search for that isbn in that book collection.

Here is a sloppy rough estimate of what I have so far:

```
   //this method is a helper function
   private String findBook(int is){
      this.isbn = is;   
      for(int i = 0; i <= collection.length; i++){
         add(isbn);
      }  
   }
```

I know this method is wrong, but I am having a lot of trouble thinking of a way to write this. How do I search this collection of type Book[] with a string parameter isbn? If you guys want my entire code let me know and I'll post it!

Thank you to whoever helps!

@drorbs Here is my data field and constructor:

```
  private int limit = 200;
   //Array of type book
   private int Book[];

   //actual size of collection, initialized to zero. Must never exceed limit
   private Book[] collection;    //collection is of book type    

   private int lastElement;

   //Constructor
   public BookCollection(int l){
      limit = l;
      int lastElement = 0;
         if(limit <= 200){
            Book[] collection = new Book[limit];
         } else{
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("CannotExceedLimit");
           }   
      }
```

Comment: `Book` should implement `Comparable`

Comment: Your method is quite a ways off, suggest you go through some java basics.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: Create a `List` of `Book` objects and use the `Collection` class to compare a `Book`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive implementation of such method would be:

```
private int findBook(String isbn){
    // iterate all the Book elements in the collection array
    for(int i = 0; i <= collection.length; i++){
        // check if the current book isbn matches the one provided argument
        if (collection[i].getIsbn().equals(isbn))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Notice the method return type should be an int if you are looking for the book index and that the `isbn` argument should be of type String.
In addition, I think `books` would be a more suitable name for the array than `collection`.

Comment: after I submitted this I was walking to class and realized i did a stupid mistake of not having the return type be of type int. Here's to being a beginner! Thank you for your answer

Comment: collection is of type Book[]. My top data field and constructor looks like this (check edit above, I put code at bottom)

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly, you want to search a Book[] for an ISBN, and return the index of the found book, or -1 if you fail to find the book?

I don't know what a Book looks like, but assuming it has a getISBN() method, and assuming collection is a Book[] you want to search, I'd create a method like:

```
private int findBook( String isbn ) {
    int returnIndex = -1;
    for ( int index = 0; index < collection.length; index++ ) {
        if ( collection[ index ].equals( isbn ) {
            returnIndex = index;
            break;
    }
    return returnIndex;
}
```

Comment: collection[ index ].equals( isbn ) will not work if collection stores Book objects should be collection[ index ].getISBN().equals( isbn )

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Library {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Library();
    }

    private List<Book> collection;

    public Library() {
        collection = Arrays.asList(
            new Book("Foo", "000-0-00-000000-1", 0.0d),
            new Book("Bar", "000-0-00-000000-2", 0.0d),
            new Book("Baz", "000-0-00-000000-3", 0.0d)
        );

        Book b = collection.get(1);

        changePrice(b.getIsbn(), 3.50);

        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public int findBook(String isbn) {
        for (Book book : collection) {
            if (book.getIsbn().equals(isbn)) {
                return collection.indexOf(book);
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public void changePrice(String isbn, double price) {
        int index = findBook(isbn);

        if (index < 0) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("BookNotFound");
        }

        collection.get(index).setPrice(price);
    }

    public class Book implements Comparable<Book> {
        private String author;
        private String isbn;
        private double price;

        public Book() {
            this.author = "NOT FOUND";
            this.isbn = "000-0-00-000000-0";
            this.price = 0.0f;
        }

        public Book(String author, String isbn, double price) {
            this.author = author;
            this.isbn = isbn;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getAuthor() {
            return author;
        }

        public void setAuthor(String author) {
            this.author = author;
        }

        public String getIsbn() {
            return isbn;
        }

        public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
            this.isbn = isbn;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        // You can use this to sort books.
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Book other) {
            return this.getIsbn().compareTo(other.getIsbn());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Book [author=%s, isbn=%s, price=$%.2f]",
                    author, isbn, price);
        }
    }
}
```